# 2010 Word "Recent Documents" not accessible

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-word-2010

I am not able to go to File/Options/Advanced, and in the Display section, change the number of Recent Documents because it is grayed out. Where do I need to got to unlock this?

Comment: Can you update with more information about if this is for you at home, or on a work PC (part of a domain), also if you're logged in / have admin permission.

Comment: Also which 'Suite' of Office you have; 'Home and Student','Home and Business', 'Standard', 'Starter', 'Professional', 'Professional Academic', 'Professional Plus'

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I'm using Office Pro 2010, Windows 7, on my personal laptop so I've got full permissions.

Answer (score 1):

This setting can be controlled by Group Policy.  If you have privacy software running on your system, you may have inadvertently enabled [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940223.aspx) policy.

Browse in your registry to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer` and look for a `NoRecentDocsHistory` value.  Delete the value or set the data to `0` and then run `gpupdate /force` or reboot.